# How to remove hide class from html element

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is a hide on `.container3`, how do I remove that hide like how it was removed from `.container2`?

Clicking the **1st** exit button removes hide from `.container2` Clicking the **2nd** exit button should remove hide from `.container3`

```
<button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>
```

How would I remove hide from `.container3` in the code?

How would it be written?

```
<div class="container3 hide"></div>
```

I currently have this: https://jsfiddle.net/u9h8fwz5/

Any answer provided, can you check first that it works in the code.

The exit button is not clickable on page 2.

To get to page 2 click the exit button.

I am not sure what needs to be done in the code.

**Clicking on this Exit button**

```
<div class="container1">
<button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>
</div>
```

**Removes This hide**
**Clicking on this Exit button**

```
<div class="container2 hide">
<button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>
</div>
```

**Should remove this hide**

```
<div class="container3 hide"></div>
```

**Html**

```
<div class="container1 ">
  <div class="ratio-keeper">
    <div class="wrap embed-youtube ">
      <div class="video embed-youtube  " data-id="djV11Xbc914">
      </div>
      <button class="playa cover playgreen  embed-youtube-play" type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>
</div>
<div class="container2 hide">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="ratio-keeper">
      <div class="wrap embed-youtube">
        <div class="video embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
        </div>
        <button class="playb cover embed-youtube-play" type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>
    <div class="ratio-keeper">
      <div class="wrap embed-youtube">
        <div class="video embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
        </div>
        <button class="playc cover embed-youtube-play" type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ratio-keeper">
      <div class="wrap embed-youtube">
        <div class="video embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
        </div>
        <button class="playd cover embed-youtube-play" type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ratio-keeper">
      <div class="wrap embed-youtube">
        <div class="video embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
        </div>
        <button class="playe cover embed-youtube-play" type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ratio-keeper">
      <div class="wrap embed-youtube">
        <div class="video embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
        </div>
        <button class="playf cover embed-youtube-play" type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container3 hide">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="ratio-keeper">
      <div class="wrap embed-youtube">
        <div class="video embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
        </div>
        <button class="playg cover embed-youtube-play" type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ratio-keeper">
      <div class="wrap embed-youtube">
        <div class="video embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
        </div>
        <button class="playh cover embed-youtube-play" type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ratio-keeper">
      <div class="wrap embed-youtube">
        <div class="video embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
        </div>
        <button class="playi cover embed-youtube-play" type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ratio-keeper">
      <div class="wrap embed-youtube">
        <div class="video embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
        </div>
        <button class="playj cover embed-youtube-play" type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ratio-keeper">
      <div class="wrap embed-youtube">
        <div class="video embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
        </div>
        <button class="playk cover embed-youtube-play" type="button" aria-label="Open"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function show(el) {
  el.classList.remove("hide");
}

function hide(el) {
  el.classList.add("hide");
}

function exitClickHandler() {
  const thewrap = document.querySelector(".container2");
  show(thewrap);
  const cover = document.querySelector(".container1");
  hide(cover);
}
```

**CSS**

```
.container2 .container {
  background: teal;
}

.container3 .container {
  background: red;
}
```

**Here was my attempt:** https://jsfiddle.net/59wjuhxv/

```
(function manageCover() {

  function hide(el) {
    el.classList.add("hide");
  }

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function exitClickHandler() {
    const thewrap = document.querySelector(".container3");
    show(thewrap);
    const cover = document.querySelector(".container1");
    hide(cover);
  }

  const cover = document.querySelector(".exit");
  cover.addEventListener("click", exitClickHandler);
}());


(function manageCover() {

  function hide(el) {
    el.classList.add("hide");
  }

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function exitClickHandler() {
    const thewrap = document.querySelector(".container2");
    show(thewrap);
    const cover = document.querySelector(".container1");
    hide(cover);
  }

  const cover = document.querySelector(".exit");
  cover.addEventListener("click", exitClickHandler);
}());
```

Comment: The code snippet you have shared here is not enough to understand your Question. Please share more of it.

Comment: You are answering your own question? How to remove hide class from html element > by using `el.classList.remove('hide')`

Comment: The question asks `How would I remove hide from .container3` but the code (`exitClickHandler`) does not mention container3 anywhere. Is the sample complete?

Comment: What would be added to exitClickHandler? I removed this hide: <div class="container2 hide"></div> How do I remove this hide? <div class="container3 hide"></div>

Comment: Clicking on the 2nd exit button should remove this hide<div class="container3 hide"></div>

Comment: Clicking 1st exit button removeshide from .container2 Clicking 2nd exit button should remove hide from .container3

Comment: Please edit your question to enhance clarity not add comments to it.

Comment: Do you understand what my question is?

Comment: "The exit button is not clickable on page 2.
To get to page 2 click the exit button."  I see no "page' or "exit" in the code.  Please read the question and add clarity with specifics to what is meant by that text rather than some obscure conceptual idea

Comment: There is a hide on .container3, how do I remove that hide like how it was removed from .container2? It's in the jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/u9h8fwz5/

Comment: I just posted the html. Now do you see it? Is that better?

Comment: I added more clarity if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle based on several measures. Here I show two examples side by side.
First example toggles the `hide` class to match your example using data attributes to say what a button targets out of convience.

Second example; I change a value of a data attribute and have CSS which indicates the color to use dependent on that value.  For this second example I could easily toggle multiple values into the same data attribute for example red/green/yellow for a stoplight if we had 3 CSS settings.

```js
function doClick(event) {
  const t = event.currentTarget.dataset.hit;
  const containerTargets = document.querySelectorAll(t);
  containerTargets.forEach(container => container.classList.toggle("hide"));
}
const actions = document.querySelectorAll(".toggle-fun");
actions.forEach(tg => tg.addEventListener("click", doClick));

function doFun(event) {
  const t = event.currentTarget.dataset.hit;
  const containerTargets = document.querySelector(".container-datafun").querySelectorAll(t);
  containerTargets.forEach(container => container.dataset.hitme = container.dataset.hitme == "yes" ? "no" : "yes");
}
const funBlock = document.querySelector(".fun-button-container");
let funs = funBlock.querySelectorAll(".toggle-d");
funs.forEach(tg => tg.addEventListener("click", doFun))
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.wrapper>* {
  border: solid lime 1px;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.containers .container1 {
  background-color: teal;
}

.containers .container2 {
  background-color: red;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.container-datafun {
  display: flex;
  margin: 1em;
}

.container-datafun>.funguy {
  border: solid blue 1px;
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.25em;
  background-color: #ffddff;
}

.container-datafun>.funguy[data-hitme="yes"] {
  background-color: #ddffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <div class="containers">
      <div class="container1">I am the 1</div>
      <div class="container2 hide">I am the 2</div>
      <div class="container3 hide">I am the 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="button-container">
      <button type="button" class="toggle-fun" data-hit=".container2">Two</button>
      <button type="button" class="toggle-fun" data-hit=".container1">One</button>
      <button type="button" class="toggle-fun" data-hit=".container1, .container2">1 and 2</button>
      <button type="button" class="toggle-fun" data-hit=".container3">Three</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>I toggle the colors using data but it could be anything.
    <div class="container-datafun">
      <div class="funguy me1">I am the 1</div>
      <div class="funguy me2">I am the 2</div>
      <div class="funguy me3">I am the 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="fun-button-container">
      <button type="button" class="toggle-d" data-hit=".funguy.me1">Two</button>
      <button type="button" class="toggle-d" data-hit=".me2">One</button>
      <button type="button" class="toggle-d" data-hit=".me1, .me2">1 and 2</button>
      <button type="button" class="toggle-d" data-hit=".me3">Three</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This was my attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/59wjuhxv/ I'm confused.

Comment: Your fiddle is WAY to complicated which is why you are in this state of confusion.
When you put those `const cover = document.querySelector(".exit");`  WHAT do you expect that to attach to?  it is attaching to the FIRST one it finds in the DOM - only.  IDK what the purpose of those two nearly identical self executing functions at the top is supposed to do, but try to SIMPLIFY all this - research DRY code and what that means.

Comment: I got it to work here, can this be improved? https://jsfiddle.net/zbvtwg06/ How would you have written it? Can you show me an edited fiddle please?

Comment: See for instance where I scope to `funBlock` then attach to elements inside that?

Comment: I don't have time right now to do a deep dive into removing much of your HTML and code ATM to simplify.